# Mantener datos en update aspx c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Estimados, estoy realizando un CRUD con entityframework en aspx c#, al consultar sobre el usuario a editar muestro los datos en varios textbox.
Lo que deseo hacer es que si el usuario borra un dato (en el textbox) y actualiza el usuario, en la base de datos se mantenga el dato ya insertado, pero lo que tengo hasta ahora es que en el sqlserver lo almacena null
Inserto código

```
public int updateUsuario(string rut, string nombre, string apellido, string contrasena, string telefono, int cargo, string correo, int tienda)
{
    //Consulto si los datos ingresados son null, y en teoría, asigno los valores devueltos por el método select (SELECT * from usuario)
    if(nombre==null)
    {
        nombre = select(rut).nombre;
    }
    if(apellido==null)
    {
        apellido = select(rut).apellido;
    }
    if(contrasena==null)
    {
        contrasena = select(rut).contrasena;
    }
    if(telefono==null)
    {
        telefono = select(rut).telefono;
    }
    if(correo==null)
    {
        correo = select(rut).correo;
    }



    byte[] enc = MD5.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(contrasena));
    StringBuilder cadena = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < enc.Length; i++)
    {
        cadena.Append(enc[i].ToString("x2"));
    }
    string comp = cadena.ToString();
    int ret = 0;
    var seach = (from us in datos.usuario where us.rut == rut select us).Single();
    seach.nombre = nombre;
    seach.apellido = apellido;
    seach.contrasena = comp;
    seach.telefono = telefono;
    seach.cargo = cargo;
    seach.correo = correo;
    seach.tienda = tienda;
    ret = datos.SaveChanges();
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entonces no reemplaces incondicionalmente el valor, sino que verifica antes que cada campo no este vacío o nulo antes de reemplazarlo

```cs
public int updateUsuario(string rut, string nombre, string apellido, string contrasena, string telefono, int cargo, string correo, int tienda)
{
    byte[] enc = MD5.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(contrasena));
    StringBuilder cadena = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < enc.Length; i++)
    {
        cadena.Append(enc[i].ToString("x2"));
    }
    string comp = cadena.ToString();
    int ret = 0;
    var seach = (from us in datos.usuario where us.rut == rut select us).Single();

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(nombre)) {
        seach.nombre = nombre;
    }

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(apellido)) {
        seach.apellido = apellido;
    }

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(comp)) {
        seach.contrasena = comp;
    }

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(telefono)) {
        seach.telefono = telefono;
    }

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(cargo)) {
        seach.cargo = cargo;
    }

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(correo)) {        
        seach.correo = correo;
    }        

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(tienda)) {
        seach.tienda = tienda;
    }

    ret = datos.SaveChanges();
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Me funcionó utilizando este método, y también el atributo.lenght==0, Gracias!